# Component style being used as global style react js

Tags: reactjs

So I created two components and stylesheets for only one of them. The components files are as follows:

Main.js component 1

```js
import "./main.css";

function Main()  {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World From Main</h1>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Main;
```

main.css

```css
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Sub.js COMPONENT 2

```js
function Sub()    {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World from Sub</h1>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Sub;
```

App.js main file

```js
import Main from "./components/Main";
import Sub from "./components/Sub";

function App()    {
    return  (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <Main />
            <Sub />
        </div>
    )
};

export default App;
```

The image is what it results in. My question is why is my `main.css` being used as the global style? How do I fix this

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtMRg.png)

I tried creating a css file for the `Sub` component called `sub.css` and linking it to the Sub component. Then I changed the h1 color over there to blue. So my final code looked like this

```js
import "./sub.css";

function Sub()    {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World from Sub</h1>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Sub;
```

```css
h1    {
    color: blue;
}
```

But then all the text goes from red to blue color. [As seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dnzo.png)

Can someone please help me on how should I resolve this. All I want is for the component style to work only for the component it is imported and not for every component. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you should use CSS modules. If you use Create React App, it's as easy as [changing style module extension to `Component.module.scss`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/).